# List of list to get element whose values greater than 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 list where each list is of size 250000. I wanted to iterate thru the lists and return the values that are greater than 3.

For example:

```
import itertools
from array import array 
import numpy as np
input = (np.array([list([8,1]), list([2,3,4]), list([5,3])],dtype=object), np.array([1,0,0,0,1,1,1]))
X = input[0]
y = input[1]
res = [ u for s in X for u in zip(y,s) ] 
res
```

I don't get the expected output.

```
Actual res : [(1, 8), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 5), (0, 3)] 
Expected output 1 : [(8,1), (1,0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 1), (5, 1), (3, 1)]
Expected output 2 : [(8,1), (4, 1), (5, 1))] ---> for greater than 3
```

I took references from stackoverflow. Tried itertools as well.

Comment: Note that you are abusing NumPy a little bit here... a NumPy array of lists gives you none of the advantages of NumPy, so a simple list of lists would work just as well. If you have structured, non-square-array data, you might want to look into Pandas.

Comment: Okay. Its tuple and not numpy array

Comment: If I wanted output like :
(([list([8]), list([4]), list([5])]), ([1,1,1])) for input (([list([8,1]), list([2,3,4]), list([5,3])]), ([1,0,0,0,1,1,1])) - how do I loop through the tuple and filter only those > 3 but also eliminate the corresponding element from 2nd tuple

Answer (score 0):

Using NumPy to store lists of non-uniform lengths creates a whole lot of issues, like the ones you are seeing. If it were an array integers, you could simply do

```py
X[X > 3]
```

but since it is an array of lists, you have to jump through all sorts of hoops to get what you want, and basically lose all the advantages of using NumPy in the first place. You could just as well use lists of lists and skip NumPy altogether.

As an alternative I would recommend using Pandas or something else more suitable than NumPy:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'data': [8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4],
    'flag': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
})

df[df['data'] > 3]
#    group  data  flag
# 0      0     8     1
# 4      1     4     1
# 5      2     5     1
# 6      2     4     1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `filter`

For example:

```
input = [1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 22]
# result contains even numbers of the list 
result = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, input)
```

This should give you `result = [2, 6, 8, 22]`

Not sureI quite understand exactly what you're trying to do... but `filter` is probably a good way.

Comment: How does `x % 2 == 0` give "greater than 3"? :)

Comment: I am not there at the expected output1 to try filter option